# Setting Matrices in GLSL Not Working

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have this shader code (GLSL):

`#version 420`

```
in vec4 vertex;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewMatrix * projectionMatrix * vertex;
}
```

If I *don't* set modelViewMatrix and projectionMatrix, it runs without error. If I do, OpenGL throws an Invalid Operation exception when I try to draw.

I set the matrices via this code:

`glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, false, sendArray);`
I have verified that "location" and "sendArray" contain the proper data. What's going on here?

EDIT: the problem appears to be in the glUniformMatrix4fv call, but I don't know what's wrong with it.

The code to set up `location` is as follows:

`GLint location;`

```
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(this->programID, uniform.c_str());

if (location == -1)
{
    throw ShaderVariableNotFoundException(uniform, this->programID);
}
```

Comment: I can't set values that are unused in GLSL because the compiler optimizes the variables away. If I try to set a value that doesn't get used in the shader, OpenGL tells me it can't find the variable.

Comment: Show the code that sets up `location`.

Comment: I checked to make sure location is valid. It's not -1 or anything.

Comment: Show the whole code. will you?

Comment: I showed the code to set up the location on the original post now, if that's what you meant by the "whole" code.

Comment: Also, FYI, I think you intend to switch the order of the matrix multiplication in your shader.

Comment: That is correct. I have since done that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it, but I'm loathe to tell you all the solution because of how embarrassing it is...

I...

I forgot to bind the shader program.

I'm so sorry for wasting all of your time.

Comment: Hahaha oh no... turns out this was my problem too!

Thanks for coming back and adding this.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing `16` for count, which is wrong.

From [the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml):

> The `count` argument indicates the number of matrices to be passed. A `count` of 1 should be used if modifying the value of a single matrix, and a `count` greater than 1 can be used to modify an array of matrices.

And you're getting the expected error, per

> `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if `count` is greater than 1 and the indicated uniform variable is not an array variable.

The notes section of the docs tells you yet again

> If `count` is greater than 1 and the indicated uniform variable is not an array, a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated and the specified uniform variable will remain unchanged.

Comment: I changed it, but unfortunately that didn't eliminate the error. Also I was confused because I thought it was the number of elements :|

But because of your help, I now recognize the problem is in the glUniformMatrix4fv function!